# Bootstrap 5 on Angular: Using the SCSS @extend Function in Components

Tags: angular, sass, components, styles, bootstrap-5

I just updated my Angular 2 Application to Bootstrap 5. And now essential things don't work anymore.

I work a lot with ***@extend*** in SCSS to keep the HTML code cleaner. In a component I use e.g.

```scss
h3 {
  @extend .mb-0;
}
```

Now there is a problem with just this @extend function from scss in my components.

In all of my projects I integrate Bootstrap as recommended in the *styles.scss*:

```scss
@import 'bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import '~src/assets/styles/my_variables.scss'; // Bootstrap variables overridden by me
@import 'bootstrap/scss/variables';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

.my_class {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

With Bootstrap 4 I was able to import the *styles.scss* file into a *component.scss* without any problems:

```scss
@import "~src/assets/styles/my_variables.scss";
@import "~src/styles.scss";

h3 {
  @extend .mb-0;
  @extend .my_class;
  color: red;
}
```

This allowed me to extend all elements with the bootstrap classes (and others).
But when I import the *styles.scss* now, **all Bootstrap's classes no longer work in these components**. The view is broken, no grid system, etc. If I don't import styles.scss into component.scss, the grid system and all bootstrap classes work again, but I can no longer use my @extend function.

Is the problem known to others? Can anybody help me further?

I've been working at Angular for about a year, and maybe there are more elegant ways to achieve my goal. I am very grateful for any tips or ideas.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I found if you load bootstrap though angular.json it will work with the utilities just fine but then you have to load bootstrap again in your styles to over ride the vars. I don't want to load bootstrap 2 times. Feels odd to me.

Comment: Interesting. If that works, I guess the building process of angular will not import it twice - but who knows...